# Sem_timedwait error on AIX

Tags: c, aix

I tried using sem_timedwait in AIX.

I got this error:

`*"ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .sem_timedwait"*`

I can guess that, i m missing some libraries.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or if AIX implements that but POSIX marks the timeout interfaces as being optional:

> [TMO][Option Start] Timeouts [Option
>   End] The functionality described is
>   optional. The functionality described
>   is also an extension to the ISO C
>   standard.

Comment: It was optional prior to POSIX 2008 (actually, all of the semaphore interfaces were optional I believe, but timed wait was just in a more-specific option group). It's now mandatory.

Comment: @R. so it depends to which version of POSIX AIX claims to be conforming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking librt?  I'd try adding -lrt to your link line.  Also pthread.

Comment: I tried adding -lrt earlier. When i added it, the AIX said "cannot find libcrt". I m using GCC on AIX

Comment: Maybe you are missing some library?  The fact that you specified -lrt (that is what you said, right?), but it complained about lib*c*rt, makes me think it recognized the -lrt as special somehow.